# Overflow with background

Tags: css, hover, overflow, margin, padding

I want to achieve the following result, without hard coded padding and margin. The background should automatically get the size of the text.
Without the padding-margin hack the extended part of the text has no background.

without mouseover:
[image: without mouseover]

with mouseover:
[image: with mouseover]

actual code:

```
.card-footer div:first-child
{
    float: left;
    max-width:200px;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.card-footer:hover div:first-child
{
    overflow:visible;
    background-color: gold;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    padding-right: 350px;
    margin-right: -350px;
}
```

HTML (from the yellow card):

[image: HTML]

Comment: where's the html? that would be helpful

Comment: I've added a picture of the HTML, but it is generated html from Salesforce Visualforce

Comment: This can heavily affect your layout in the future. Maybe you should invest some time and investigate for tooltip solutions, or just use the `title` attribute to show the full text on hover. Another way would be to set the content element to `position: absolute;` on hover as well, so it won't move other boxes arround.

Comment: It doesn't affect the other content and to solution with padding and margin works fine. But it is hard coded and did not adjust itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have an inline-element inheriting background properties:

```css
p {
  background: yellow;
  border: solid;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

span {
  background: inherit
}
```

```html
<p><span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</span></p>
```

snippet without text-overflow rules, this is your hover style.

Comment: How can I cover the zero ?

Comment: @DavidRenz add : position:relative to the other span , it will bring it up front